# What is the origin of "mThis"?

Tags: android

We have some devs on Android part of our application who actively use prefixing of class member variables with "m*".

What is the origin of "mThis" which is basically:

```
class SomeClass {
    private final SomeClass mThis;
    SomeClass() {
        mthis = this;
    }
}
```

and this notation in general?

Comment: That code doesn't make a lot of sense; its only benefit (AFAIK) is slightly simplifying the syntax for accessing enclosing class members from a non-static inner class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I guess the question is more about the m-prefix, not the goal of having `this` as your own field.

So regarding the prefix, this is [a coding convention used by android team](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#follow-field-naming-conventions): all member variables (aka fields) are prefixed with "m". That's it, basically. Other android developers might use it because they have browsed through android sources and have deemed it appropriate to use this convention in their own code.

BTW, it's not common in general java programming, I believe common java coding standards usually discourage using any kind of prefixes for anything.

Comment: Yes, this is more about the convention they use. Is it any-how c-related?

Comment: The article is about the Android project source code, so why do devs use the same code convention in applications development?

Comment: well, you should ask them :) I, for one, do not use it, sticking to my general java style

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Conventional Java naming convention set forth by Sun back in the 90's doesn't use any prefix like 'm'. It just uses lowerCamelCase for variables.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it comes handy when you need to pass a reference to the instance in an inner class, and you don't want to use the "fully qualified" **this**. i.e `SomeClass.this`. Nevertheless, it seems redundant to me.

Comment: What about all other member variables which are m-prefixed?

Answer (score 0):

[This article suggests it comes from ancient habits peculiar to the Microsoft ecosystem](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/06/17/the-religion-of-class-member-prefixing.aspx) -- however, prefixing members of `struct`s with some shorthand of the `struct` it is contained in is an *old* C habit from the days when identifiers, *all* identifiers (include structure member names), had to be unique in the first eight characters. Prefixing the names with a short-hand version of the name of the containing structure was an easy mechanism to ensure unique names:

```
struct inode {
    int number;
    struct device *dev;
}

struct file_descriptor {
    int number;
    struct inode *i;
}
```

In this case, `number` is duplicated, non-unique, and trouble.

Newer versions of C made this a non-issue by placing `struct` names into their namespaces, but some portion of this habit has carried over: the Linux kernel, for example, is filled with:

```
struct iattr {
    unsigned int    ia_valid;
    umode_t     ia_mode;
    uid_t       ia_uid;
....
```

and

```
struct inode {
    /* RCU path lookup touches following: */
    umode_t         i_mode;
    uid_t           i_uid;
    gid_t           i_gid;
    const struct inode_operations   *i_op;
    struct super_block  *i_sb;
...
```

where the leading `ia_` and `i_` are from the `struct iattr` and `struct inode` -- which makes it slightly easier to read chains like this:

```
if (!IS_ERR(cookie) && path->dentry->d_inode->i_op->put_link)
    path->dentry->d_inode->i_op->put_link(path->dentry, nd, cookie);
```

(Really. `fs/namei.c`, lines 821 and 822 in my source.)

Answer (score 0):

It avoids accidently using a local variable when you meant to use the member (which the m is short for) variable of the object.

```
private String name;
private String mName;
public void setName(String name) {
    name = name; //wrong, just set the parameter variable to itself
    this.name = name; //ok, but has 'this.' which isn't a problem, but some people don't like it
    mName = name; //simples
}
```

Answer (score 0):

m for member variables, s for statics. It's a common naming convention. But like neutrino I don't use it very much. If you use a modern IDE, the syntax color-coding gives you the same information (actually more, because it works whether the original coder followed the naming convention or not).

Answer (score -1):

I use the m prefix to define global variables for the class instance. I don't know why, but when I started and looked over other android code, it was like that.

Comment: "global variables for the class instance" - not member functions but just members.